# My C++ makefile can not create object file for each .cpp code

Tags: c++, makefile

My makefile compiles our C++ code without any problems but it can not create object files.

How do I need to modify this file in order to create the object file for each `.cpp` file?
Is there any problem if I proceed without creating an object file for each `.cpp` file ?

My makefile looks like this:

```
engine:main.cpp correlation.cpp correlation.h matcher.cpp matcher.h scheduler.cpp scheduler.h parser.cpp parser.h cache_manager.cpp cache_manager.h init.cpp init.h db_manager.cpp db_manager.h
    g++ -o engine main.cpp correlation.cpp correlation.h matcher.cpp matcher.h scheduler.cpp scheduler.h parser.cpp parser.h cache_manager.cpp cache_manager.h init.cpp init.h db_manager.cpp db_manager.h -lpthread -lboost_regex -I/usr/include -ggdb \
    -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client \
    -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -lclntsh -locci
clean:
     rm -f engine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem if you skip *naming* object  files. They'll still be created behind the scenes though.

The advantage of specifically creating object files is that you'll save time recompiling, since *make* will be able to skip any object file it doesn't have to recreate (since it's up-to-date; something that won't work with temporary files as they're deleted).

The easiest way to get this working is by using a special placeholder syntax in your makefile:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $< $(YOUR_OTHER_PARAMS)
```

In this example you define a generic recipe for any file ending in `.o` to requiring a file with the same name ending in `.cpp`. `$@` is a special macro that will expand to the current output file, while `$<` will include the current input file.

In a similar way you may define macros for other files as well:

```
%.png: %.bmp
    myinmageconverter -png $< $@
```

You can still name specific recipes, e.g. for cases where one specific file needs additional or different parameters. Just name it in your makefile as usual. The placeholder syntax will only try to match otherwise unmatched targets.

If you'd like to mention some generic or precompiled header, you can still include it (just like any other dependency):

```
%.o: %.cpp common.hpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $< $(YOUR_OTHER_PARAMS)
```

For the actual executable, you can then just define your components as usual, i.e. your example could look like this:

```
engine: main.o correlation.o matcher.o scheduler.o ...
    g++ -o engine main.o correlation. matcher.o ...

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $< -lpthread -lboost_regex -I/usr/include -ggdb ...
```

Comment: Mario thank u very much my problem solved by ur answer thank u sir.Sorry about let response

Comment: @sis No worries, most don't answer anyway, but people here generally post for fun. You could mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you, so others can see/find the issue as a solved issue.